# Ubuntu server hangs on reboot "could not stat resume device file"

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Instead of booting into the running system this machine stops and on the terminal I can see a message:

```
could not stat resume device file /dev/sdb5
```

When I attach a keyboard and press enter the boot continues and the machine comes up like normal.

But it's essential that this machine comes up under most circumstancs alone.

There never was something like a "resume" on this machine.

I tried several times to reboot, but this does not happen on all boots, I can not find a pattern here.

There is a software raid running on the box.

How can I get rid of this boot failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like sdb5 is *supposed* to be swap, but it's broken. It can be fixed by using `swapoff /dev/sdb5` to make sure it's not in use, then `mkswap /dev/sdb5`. Of course, you should consult your system installation notes to verify that it should be a swap partition first.

Comment: You solved it, thank you! I did just remove the sdb5 swap line from fstab, it was from an old install. There is another swap partition now, which is in use and works. So there were 2 swap entries in fstab.

Comment: Having multiple swap entries isn't necessarily a problem. Linux will balance accesses between the various swap partitions in order to optimize for speed.

Comment: Amazing. Good to know. Well in this case the partition did not exist anymore.